# ASP.NET Web Forms - How to redirect and pass parameters without problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, parameters, webforms

I wanted to redirect (by code) to another ASPX page and on that page I wanted to select the appropriate view (in a multi-view and during page load).

My solution was to add a url parameter that was checked on the "OnLoadComplete" event and take appropriate action, but it seems that this url parameter gets copied to all the links on the page. So, the user cannot navigate anywhere else because always this view gets presented.

My second thought was to use a Session variable, but I am afraid that this will be an overkill.

Any ideas/thoughts/suggestions on this matter?

- Can I prevent the use of the url parameter in all the page-links?
- Is it bad if I use a Session variable for this temporarily?
- Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: why a session variable is an overkill? They are there for that, a simple bool or int will not kill your application's performance...

Comment: I am just influenced by people demonizing Session variables I guess:
https://www.google.com/search?q=why+avoid+session+variables.  However, I don't see any other suggestions, so I guess I will go with that option...

Comment: Well, you should not store in session variables a tree of objects with thousands of items, but a flag indicating if you must do a certain task is more than acceptable, just remember to reset it when it's not needed and you should be ok

Comment: (By overkill I meant if this solution is an exaggeration, but since I see no alternatives, I guess that it isn't... )
OK. Thanks! :)